# Syntax trees: free monad + Bound.Scope

Tags: haskell, abstract-syntax-tree, free-monad

I'm attempting to define an abstract syntax type using ekmett's libraries `bound` and `free`. I have something working, which I can strip down to the following minimal example:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

import Bound
import Control.Monad.Free

type Id = String

data TermF f α =
    AppF α α
  | BindF Id (Scope () f α)
  deriving Functor

newtype Term' α = T {unT :: Free (TermF Term) α}
type Term = Free (TermF Term')
```

Those last two lines are, uh, not what I was hoping for. They make it kind of a PITA to actually exploit the open recursion for annotations (or whatever).

**Is there a better way of using these two libraries together, and/or should I just give up on trying to make `Term` a free monad?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Make it simple

You can simplify the last two lines into.

```
newtype Term α = T {unT :: Free (TermF Term) α}
```

This should help you know to consistently use `T` and `unT` everywhere instead of only at every other level.

#### Make it complicated

Both `Free` and `TermF` have the kind `(*->*)->(*->*)`, which is the kind of a transformer. You are looking for the fixed point of the composition of `Free` and `TermF`. We can write the composition of transformers in general.

```
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}

newtype ComposeT g h f a = ComposeT { unComposeT :: g (h f) a}
    deriving Functor
```

We can also write the fixed point of transformers in general.

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

newtype FixT t a = FixT { unFixT :: t (FixT t) a }

deriving instance Functor (t (FixT t)) => Functor (FixT t)
```

Then you could write

```
type Term = FixT (ComposeT Free TermF)
```

Then use `FixT . ComposeT` everywhere you would have just used `T` and `unComposeT . unFixT` everywhere you would have used `unT`.